# WebDriver Automation for Clicking the Row-Checker checkbox in GWT GRID

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, dom, webdriver

How can I automate the clicking of checkbox in a particular row in a GWT GRID. I am using Selenium WebDriver with Java bindings. 
I am not able to get a way to assign IDs into the cells/row-checker checkbox. Below is the code how a checkbox column is rendered in the grid panel.

```
 CheckboxSelectionModel checkboxSelectionModel;
 CheckboxColumnConfig checkboxColumnConfig;
 checkboxSelectionModel = new CheckboxSelectionModel();
 gridPanel.setSelectionModel(checkboxSelectionModel);
```

If setting Ids to the ckeck-box is not possible, even I am ready to write some javascript function to identify the chek-box, so that I can click on that. 
Please help/.

below HTML :

```
<td id="ext-gen130" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-checker x-grid3-cell-first " tabindex="0" style="width:18px;">
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-checker">
<div id="ext-gen129" class="x-grid3-row-checker">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</td>
```

being generated for the row checker.

Answer (score 0):

Try using clickAt with 0,0 coord. I found out a minute ago, works for me in IDE.

Edit:
Sorry, I had a slightly different problem with clicking checkbox in the grid. I was able to locate it, but clicking did not work for me in IDE. Whereas it works in Python WebDriver which is sufficient for me.

For your case: I am not sure, what is stable/dynamic for you, but try clicking at the deepest div. My case is a little bit different but very similar; this worked as a locator to be clicked:

```
//span[text()='[searched cell in the grid]']/../../../td[1]/div/div
```

td[1] identifies the first column of the table where I have the checkbox. Above that, there is the row level.

This is my simplified HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-checker x-grid3-cell-first ">
        <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-checker">
            <div class="x-grid3-row-checker">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-name ">
        <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-name">
            <span class="active-name">[searched cell in the grid]</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: could you please post a sample code, or any link which details about ?